# Terminal file find location

Tags: terminal, batch, terminal.app

I am using a mac terminal (`.command`) file to launch a Python program.

My question is, how can I find the location of the `.command` file when I am inside of the `.command` file.

Thank you.

Comment: Use `pwd` maybe?

Comment: @Vinayak No... :(

Comment: [How about this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5756763/1768141)?

Comment: @Vinayak YES! This works. Thanks so much. If you make it into an answer I can mark it as correct.

Comment: No need. Just upvote the linked answer.